# How do I get __matmul__ of two different numpy.ndarray subclasses to return a particular subclass?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `np.ndarray` subclasses.  `Tuple @ Matrix` returns a `Tuple`, but `Matrix @ Tuple` returns a `Matrix`.  How might I have it return a `Tuple` instead?

```
import numpy as np

class Tuple(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

class Matrix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

def scaling(x, y, z):
    m = Matrix(np.identity(4))
    m[0, 0] = x
    m[1, 1] = y
    m[2, 2] = z
    return m
```

example:

```
>>> Tuple([1,2,3,4]) @ scaling(2,2,2)
Tuple([2., 4., 6., 4.])

>>> scaling(2,2,2) @ Tuple([1,2,3,4])
Matrix([2., 4., 6., 4.])   # XXXX I'd like this to be a Tuple
```

PS: `Matrix @ Matrix` should return `Matrix`

Comment: Under what conditions do you want the multiplication result to be a Tuple?

Comment: There is a class parameter that helps determine what array subclass a `ufunc` returns, something like `__array_priority__`.  It's set higher for the `np.matrix` class so that class has priority over the base `ndarray`.  Look up the `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in copying from the `np.matrix` example.

```
class Tuple(np.ndarray): 
    __array_priority__ = 10 
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None): 
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls) 
class Matrix(np.ndarray):
    __array_priority__ = 5.0 
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None): 
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

In [2]: def scaling(x, y, z):  
   ...:      ...:     m = Matrix(np.identity(4))  
   ...:      ...:     m[0, 0] = x  
   ...:      ...:     m[1, 1] = y  
   ...:      ...:     m[2, 2] = z  
   ...:      ...:     return m  
   ...:                                                                                                                                  
In [3]: Tuple([1,2,3,4]) @ scaling(2,2,2)                                                                                                
Out[3]: Tuple([2., 4., 6., 4.])
In [4]: scaling(2,2,2) @ Tuple([1,2,3,4])                                                                                                
Out[4]: Tuple([2., 4., 6., 4.])
```

===

Taking a clue from the `np.matrix` definition: numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.py

Add a `__array_priority__` attribute:

```
In [382]: class Tuple(np.ndarray): 
     ...:     def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None): 
     ...:         __array_priority = 10 
     ...:         return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls) 
     ...:  
     ...: class Matrix(np.ndarray): 
     ...:     def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None): 
     ...:         __array_priority = 5 
     ...:         return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls) 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [383]:                                                                                            
In [383]: def scaling(x, y, z): 
     ...:     m = Matrix(np.identity(4)) 
     ...:     m[0, 0] = x 
     ...:     m[1, 1] = y 
     ...:     m[2, 2] = z 
     ...:     return m 
     ...:                                                                                            
In [384]: Tuple([1,2,3,4]) @ scaling(2,2,2)                                                          
Out[384]: Tuple([2., 4., 6., 4.])
In [385]: scaling(2,2,2) @ Tuple([1,2,3,4])                                                          
Out[385]: Matrix([2., 4., 6., 4.])
```

Comment: The last line of your own example is a demonstration of this not working :-) (the last line should say Tuple instead of Matrix).  But it did lead me to something that works and is also cool!  `__array_priority` needs to change to `__array_priority__`.  It also needs to move from the method body to the class body of each class.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `__matmul__` method to return a `Tuple` - and if you want to be a `Tuple` if any of the variables is a `Tuple` and a `Matrix` otherwise, I think this'll work:

```
class Matrix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __matmul__(m1, m2):
         return (m2.T @ m1.T).T if isinstance(m2, Tuple) else np.matmul(m1, m2)
```

Comment: (Matrix @ Matrix) should return Matrix. (Tuple @ Matrix) or (Matrix @ Tuple) should return Tuple.

Comment: Please add your comment to the question, as it is an important clarification.

Comment: I've edited my answer, it's not a very elegant solution but I'm not sure if any other is possible. Please check it...

Comment: Thanks. This simpler variation of your solution seems to work in all three cases (M @ M, M @ T, T @ M)    
    `def __matmul__(m1, m2):
        return type(m2)(np.matmul(m1, m2))`

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is by implementing a custom `__matmul__` in `Matrix` and `__rmatmul__` in `Tuple`:

```
import numpy as np

class Tuple(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __rmatmul__(self, other):
        return super().__matmul__(other)

class Matrix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Matrix):
            return NotImplemented
        return super().__matmul__(other)

def scaling(x, y, z):
    m = Matrix(np.identity(4))
    m[0, 0] = x
    m[1, 1] = y
    m[2, 2] = z
    return m

scaling(2,2,2) @ scaling(2,2,2)
# Matrix([[4., 0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 4., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 4., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
Tuple([1,2,3,4]) @ scaling(2,2,2)
# Tuple([2., 4., 6., 4.])
scaling(2,2,2) @ Tuple([1,2,3,4])
# Tuple([2., 4., 6., 4.])
```

Answer (score -2):

Just overload `__matmul__` of `Matrix` class to return tuple instead

```py
class Matrix(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return other @ self
```

Comment: Matrix multiplication is not symmetric, it'll return the wrong result.